# Declare different typename once based on string

Tags: c++, templates, vector, decltype

Lets say I have a function that is defined as

Edit: Added more details and reframed the question, thanks for the input

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void doSomething(string str, vector<A> arrA, vector<B> arrB) {
  if (str == "a") {
     create<A>(arrA);
  } else if (str == "b") {
     create<B>(arrB);
  }
}
 
template<typename X>
void create(vector<X> arrX) {
  // do something with arrX
}
```

Im trying to decrease the if-else statements in the function so I don't have to repeat create again and again. How would I go bout this?

Comment: "_one that holds the typenames A and B_": What do you mean with that?

Comment: Can we get more of an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want one vector that can hold multiple types? Or do you want A & B to have the same interface? Remember that C++ is a typesafe language so mixing types is not really possible. Unless you count std::variant

Comment: "_I have more typenames and parameters in the original function and am trying to find a way to decrease the if-else statements in my function._": Show an example of that, so you can get answers that actually help with your real problem instead of what you imagine the solution approach to be (which may or may not be a good approach).

Comment: something like vector<typename> arrT = {A, B}, not sure what would go in the <> angle brackets

Comment: just guess, but you may want to specialize the function instead of put all thing together with if else.

Comment: @Sahl That doesn't work even in principle. Types are not objects/values or first-class in C++.

Comment: are you looking for [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) ?

Comment: `vector<typename> arrT = {A, B}` its not only `typename` thats unclear in there. Note that `typename` is a keyword in C++ with specific meaning, while I think you just refer to the name of some type. It is also unclear what you mean with `= { A, B}` because you are using types where I'd expect values

Comment: can you explain what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What is the issue where you think `vector<typename> arrT = {A, B}` would be a solution?

Comment: @user17732522 made changes to the post, I think its easier to understand now

Comment: Is the value of `str` something you know at compile time or only at run time?

Comment: what are you doing with the value returned from `create` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the value of str is known at compile time, Im changing the value of a variable to the first element of the array that goes thorough, for simplicity I just returned it in the function

Comment: its still not very clear. However, how about passing only one vector to the function and when you call the function you do `if (str == "a") doSomething(A); else doSomething(B);` thats only a single `if-else`  (.... compared to only 1. It is difficult to help avoiding code when you do not show the code to be avoided. There is only a single if-else in your code and from what you explained I think you do need one)

Comment: Have you considered using polymorphism - or perhaps `std::variant`?

Comment: Do you have to send all those parameters to **doSomething** ?

Comment: Yes, there's more going on but this is the main part

Comment: Maybe you could do something with `enable_if` using the value of `str` to "switch" between the functions being called.

Comment: `create<A>(arrA);` can just be `create(arrA);`. Then I don't really see how this could be simpler. You need to map strings to variable names somewhere anyway, so why not with `if`/`else`? How would a simpler map look like?

Comment: @Sahl Unfortunately, it is not clear what exactly your function does with the parameters, but for less repetition **else-if**  maybe you can use a switch that makes your code more readable, and for less repetition of  **create**  maybe you can create another template that has the value you want and send it to the function only once. And in **create<A>** you don't need to pass **A** to that function because the function itself will recognize its type.

Comment: @Mahdy.n switch doesn't work with strings, and wouldn't be any shorter than a bunch of if/else if it did.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know, but he uses a char, so he might as well use **char** instead of string, also **switch** makes the code more readable and there is no need to write else-if every time